# java programming style vs Objective c

Tags: java, android, objective-c, ios

I am a iOS programmer so confident with objective c. I have also naturally programmed in Java. I am branching out into android programming and was wondering about the different programming approaches.

I have read in many different articles that there are significant differences between programming in a Java style and a Objective c/ c++ style. Whilst I know the languages are different. I was wondering if there are any Java/Android/iOS programmers that could give any pointers for someone branching out in android?

Cheers

Comment: I'd recommend reading the introductory documents and coming back when you have specific questions.

Comment: If you've programmed in Java, what's the actual issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, definetly, both architecture iPhone and android are very different, but there are many similarities also, you should start with simiilarites, which would increase your learning speed, later as need arise, you can learn differences also.

Like iOS application have AppDelegate as a single class, existed lifetime of the application. In android, though not mandatory but you can have an application class, which can work similarly as AppDelegate. In iOS screens are designed in nib files, android also has a gui tool to design screens. But its not simply drag-drop and you also supposed to understand screen size variety in android.

Android does not follow, MVC architecture fully, and it makes a big difference, but if you still want to follow MVC framework, there is an open source api, on google code, by whivh you can implement mvvc architecture in android applications.